# RavenDB permission issue when upgrading from 960 to 2230

Tags: c#, authorization, ravendb

I'm trying to upgrade to RavenDB 2.0 (build 2230) from build 960. I've restored the DB to the new version, but I'm getting an error when trying to create my indexes.

This is the line of code:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(DataAccessFactory).Assembly, documentStore);
```

And this is the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight-3.5.dll
>
> {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}

I'm using the same authorization line, as the previous version, in the app config file:

```
<add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value="server\PrestoDatabaseUser"/>
```

Note, it works correctly if this is set to all, but I don't want to do that.

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

Note, I also gave PrestoDatabaseUser full access to the Data folder.

**Does RavenDB 2.0 work differently? Is there something new to do, or am I missing something?**

The only other change I made, in the config file, was from this:

```
<add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Database\System"/>
```

To this:

```
<add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Data"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RavenDB 2.0 has strongly security measures.

This is no longer relevant:

```
 <add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value="server\PrestoDatabaseUser"/>
```

You need to configure those from the studio, see: http://ravendb.net/docs/server/authentication